# Careers student-status not actively updated in summary

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

When I toggle the checkbox associated with the text:

> I am currently a student

it displays `saving` then `✔ saved`. However this doesn't actively add/remove the:

> Currently a **student**

at top of the CV page. A page refresh is needed.

Considering all other content is changed actively, think this should be changed.