# Bold / Italics in codeblocks

Tags: discussion, support, code-formatting, code-block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bold code in a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question)
>   [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote)

Am I missing something? Can one not put either bold or italics inside codeblocks / anything that looks like them (Would have been helpful in [Careers student-status not actively updated in summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163610/careers-student-status-not-actively-updated-in-summary))?

Comment: IMO it is unnecessary. Code blocks are supposed to contain code, not formatted text. Make comments to highlight important parts as you'd do in an actual code editor if you need.

Comment: It would have been helpful in that particular post because you're abusing code formatting for something that's not code. You should simply not have used the code formatting there.

Comment: @Bart - Okay. How would you prefer I alter the question to make the text on the page the question is about, stick out from my words?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote) and [Bold code in a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question) (with workarounds).

Answer (score 0):

It would be very nice to be able to highlight the relevant sections of code.  Sometimes a large chunk has to be put in for the context, but it ends up obscuring the portion that should be focused on.

When I work on code many times I'll highlight the portion I'm working on (by selecting) so that I can focus on it better.