# Seemingly unrelated linked question(s)

Tags: support, linked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whoa! What is this “Linked” thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48076/whoa-what-is-this-linked-thing)

Just noticed one of my questions today ( [Bold / Italics in codeblocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163611/bold-italics-in-codeblocks) ) has two "linked" questions that (unless I am blind) aren't manually specified in the question / answers / comments. I therefore presume that they are manually linked.

- [Do not delete *edited* vote-to-close auto-comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47443/do-not-delete-edited-vote-to-close-auto-comments?lq=1)
- [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified?lq=1)

So, some questions:

1. Am I correct that these are manually linked
2. Are there any automated / manual processes for removing them?

Comment: Those two questions sound very related to me.